# How to post four parameters from ajax to MVC API controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to post 4 parameters from AJAX to MVC api method.
Api method is called but all variables have default values.
**Year** and **month** is zero and **app** and **levels** has null value.

Any idea what is an issue in my code?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/home/GetLogList",
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { year: 2017, month: 5, app: "hello", levels: ["aa", "bb"] },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (logs) {
        alert("successs");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("fail");
    }
})
```

API

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/home/GetLogList")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Log>> GetLogList(int year, int month, string app, IEnumerable<string> levels)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var refreshedLogs = await GetLogList(client, year, month, app, null);
        return refreshedLogs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the success function called? Also try putting quotationmarks around the keys of the data object.

Comment: Can't you use the URL QueryString?
url: "/api/home/GetLogList?year=2017&month=5&app="hello"&levels="aa"&levels="bb"

Comment: add [FromBody] on api action.

Comment: @Glubus yes success funcion is called. Problem is how to post data, not how to return.

Comment: @Ayvaras I added, [FromBody] for every parameter in method but result is same.

Comment: @Shadowfox maybe, I did't try but I would like to post data. Query string is complicated with to many parameters. Especially since I can have log 'levels ' array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your only solution is to create a viewModel for the method parameters?

```
public class LogListVM {
  public int year { get; set; } 
  public int month { get; set; } 
  public string app { get; set; } 
  public IEnumerable<string> levels { get; set; } 
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/home/GetLogList")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Log>> GetLogList(LogListVM params)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var refreshedLogs = await GetLogList(client, params.year, params.month, params.app, null);
    return refreshedLogs;
  }
}
```

JS does not change.

Comment: Yes this is only way I could implement. With two small changes. Method parameter must be [FromBody] and in Java scrip must be used JSON.stringify(...)

Answer (score 0):

> contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

data type to send in json format - in your case you need to convert into json

> dataType: 'json'

Return type of data from server to json

```
$.ajax({
url: "/api/home/GetLogList",
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // data type to be send to server in json format
method: 'POST',
dataType: 'json', // return type of data from server - should be json
data:JSON.stringify( { year: 2017, month: 5, app: "hello", levels: ["aa", "bb"] }),

success: function (logs) {
    alert("successs");
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("fail");
}
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say. It is clear what is contentType and dataType. But I am not sure what you suggest to change in my code?

Comment: contentType:json its mean you its must necessary you need you change your data to json format before to send it using method JSON.stringify()